# PyQt5: QApplication unexpectedly exits when QMessageBox is called as a menu action from QSystemTrayIcon

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

The code below is a simplified version of the code I am writing. The purpose of this PyQt5 code is to display an icon in the system tray while some system maintenance process is running, and to give the user an opportunity to terminate the maintenance process before it finishes normally, which for example would be the case when the process takes too long to complete.

The code below demonstrates the problem I have encountered. MenuItem2, when invoked, creates a QMessageBox asking user to click "ok" or "cancel". When user's response is received, the whole QApplication terminates. I have no idea why this happens. I added time.sleep(2) just to demonstrate that QMessageBox works just fine and the "if" block after QMessageBox.exec() executes normally with QApplication working normally, but as soon as the "if" block is executed and dialog_ok_cancel() function finishes the whole QApplication terminates which is evidenced by the disappearance of the system tray icon immediately after printing messages within the "if" block.

On the contrary, MenuItem1 works just fine and QApplication continues to run. Here is the code:

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSystemTrayIcon, QApplication, QMenu, QMessageBox

def menuitem1_action():
    print('MenuItem1 chosen')

def dialog_ok_cancel():
    msgBox = QMessageBox()
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
    msgBox.setText('Do you really want to terminate this process?')
    msgBox.setWindowTitle('Confirm your choice')
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
    returnValue = msgBox.exec()
    time.sleep(2)
    if returnValue == QMessageBox.Ok:
        print('OK clicked')
    else:
        print('Cancel clicked')

class SystemTrayIcon(QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon):
        QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon)
        menu = QMenu()
        item1 = menu.addAction('MenuItem1')
        item1.triggered.connect(menuitem1_action)
        item2 = menu.addAction('MenuItem2')
        item2.triggered.connect(dialog_ok_cancel)
        self.setContextMenu(menu)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon('gtk-save.png'))
trayIcon.show()

app.exec()
```

I don't mind the termination of QApplication when the user clicks on "Ok". The problem is that the application terminates when the user clicks on "Cancel" despite the fact that there is nothing in the code above causing QApplication to quit.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. From the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) of the "QApplication" class:

> The application quits when the last window was successfully closed;
> this can be turned off by setting quitOnLastWindowClosed to false.

Apparently, QSystemTrayIcon does not qualify as a window. The dialog window that opens up on an invocation of MenuItem2 is then the only window, and when it is closed on user's clicking either "Ok" or "Cancel", the whole QApplication exits.

Adding

```
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
```

immediately below "app = QApplication(sys.argv)" solves the problem.